# Android string.xml getting corrupted

Tags: android, xml, corruption, multiple-languages

I haven't been able to find answers, and I suspect I'm in the minority.

I'm starting to do languages in my android app.  But every once and a while, languages will get corrupted when I save them.

Here is an example of the corruption:

```
<string-array name="country_arrays">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>ру�?�?кий</item> <!-- should be русский, but sometimes it gets corrupted. -->
</string-array>
```

Does anyone know why this would happens?
 -Is it a problem with eclipse?
  -With Unicode?
-Maybe the combination of the two?
-Or maybe my Subversion client?

Thoughts? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(picture from android studio)
check this in your editor .. set it to utf8

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I didn't even think of that.  I'll give it a try, and if it lasts a week, I'll give you a thumbs up.  Thanks.